# Excel Services, Save As does not show Publish Options

Tags: excel-services

I have created a document library and configure it to have a Document Template Excel Spreadsheet. When I create a new Document and then save the new Excel worksheet, by selecting File -> Save&Send -> Save to SharePoint and select the document library the Publish Options button is not shown.

I gues that this is a configuration issue. I have checked the configuration for Excel Services Application but I cant find any obvious cause.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you made the Excel template the default content type for the document library and you click on the "new" button to create a document from there, simply clicking the save icon will save your document back to that document library.  Since the document library was the "source" of the new spreadsheet, you do not need to configure it as the publishing target.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Publish the workbook to SharePoint, not just save it there, this won't work.

An Excel document, for example, would not be available to Excel Services because it was not properly published to SharePoint.